# Make pytest ignore pytest.ini

Tags: python, pytest

Does `pytest` have a command line flag to make it ignore the pytest.ini file? I see the `--noconftest` flag to disable `conftest.py`, but `pytest --help` doesn't seem to have anything for disabling `pytest.ini`.

Comment: I use `pytest -c /dev/null`, most probably Windows offers something similar (`pytest -c NUL`?)

Comment: Exactly - `pytest -c NUL` works under Windows.

Comment: @hoefling this should be an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AFAIK right now `pytest` doesn't offer a command line option to ignore the configuration completely. As a workaround, you can either rename `pytest.ini` or pass the null device as config source:

```
$ pytest -c /dev/null
```

(or

```
$ pytest -c NUL
```

on Windows).